# Upgrade existing visual

Tags: powerbi

I would like to take existing visual in PowerBI (table) and add a new (simple) feature. Can this be done?

I can create new visual in PowerBI devtools but in this I can not use existing visual. If I take it from github, it is not just one ts file, but many related.

Or can I create visual which will extend (like in OOP) current visual? Which would call current update and do something else.